# How can model misfit introduce dependency?

Tags: regression, modeling, linear-model, independence, diagnostic

I read somewhere recently that mis-fitting a regression model can introduce dependency into the model. Unfortunately I cannot find the where I read this. Can anyone explain how mis-fitting a regression model can introduce dependency into the model?

Comment: It partly depends on what you mean by dependency. I give one example in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one example:

Consider you have a quadratic relationship between $y$ and $t$ ($t=1,2,3,...,n$), but fit a linear one, Now compute the ACF of the residuals:

[image]

It doesn't have to involve time or quadratics, that's just an easy form of misfit to describe and of dependence to check. Imagine you have a grouping variable (0/1) on which the mean $y$ differs, and you fit only an intercept. Then the error terms on the misspecified models within the groups are positively correlated* and across the groups are negatively correlated.

* akin to an intra-class correlation in a random-intercept mixed effects model.

Here's the R code I used to get the above plot:

```
t = 1:100
y = 43-15.1*t+0.2*t*t+rnorm(100)
misfit = lm(y~t)
acf(misfit$residuals,30)
```